# Cocos/Spritebuilder Transitions

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I'm making a project with SpriteBuilder. 
What I would like to know is if there is anyway of transitioning when I make a layer visible?

For example when I change scenes, I uses this `replaceScene:scene withTransition:[CCTransition transitionPushWithDirection:CCTransitionDirectionLeft duration:0.25f`.
Now I have a `CCNode` Layer in my `SpriteBuilder` project which is hidden, I also have a button to show this hidden node.

```
- (void)rules {

    _rules.visible = TRUE;
}
```

Is there any way I could make a transition when I make `_rules` visible?

Also when I make the node visible, it still allows me to press buttons behind the node. 
Any way to stop this?

Comment: yes, just use regular actions like move, scale, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fade in action, for example:

```
- (void)rules {

    _rules.visible = YES;
    [_rules runAction:[CCActionFadeIn actionWithDuration:1.0]];

}
```

Comment: I dont see any difference by adding that piece of code? anything else i need to add?

Comment: I've tried that and it works on a simple test project, so I don't think you need to add anything extra.

Comment: Im not sure what else to do? ive tried CCActionFadeIn CCActionFadeOut CCActionFadeTo nothing makes a difference. Ive made the duration very large and also 1 but i see no difference.

Comment: Can you make a brand new test project and try this with a sprite?